# Búsqueda en Google Sheets con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Por favor si me podrían orientar con la solución para realizar una búsqueda en base al ingreso de un id en una celda, contra los datos de una hoja de google y que me devuelva el número de dicha fila que coincida.

Tengo el siguiente código y no logro comparar el id con los valores de la hoja.

```html
function buscar(){
var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var hoja = libro.getActiveSheet();
var IdABuscar = hoja.getRange("H2").getValue();
var filaEncontrada= buscarID(IdABuscar);
Logger.log(filaEncontrada);
hoja.getRange(7,9).setValue(filaEncontrada);
}

function buscarID(id) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var valores = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()+1, sheet.getLastColumn());

for(var x=0; x<valores.length; x++){

if(id == valores[x][6]){
return x;
}
}
return 0; // Error, Id d usuario no encontrada
}
```

Nota: adjunto el link de la hoja que contiene los datos para la búsqueda:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C26U2ulYBfVR8nhBtr7Y2GZ0hX539ShcJafRACwVsqs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Bienvenido. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben de incluir un [mcve]. En este caso el código incluido está bien pero falta, primero el error textual e información de la hoja de cálculo para poder reproducir el problema. Lo usual es crear una hoja de cálculo de demostración con datos ficticios pero representativos y compartir ese hoja de cálculo con cualquiera que tenga el enlace para ver solamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está que en la condición has usado un índice base 1 en lugar de usar uno base 0.

```
id == valores[x][6]
```

debería ser

```
id == valores[x][5]
```

---

Explicación

En Google Apps Script los métodos de `Class SpreadsheetApp` y sus clases hijas  como `getRow()`, `getColumn()` devuelven "índices" base 1, por ejemplo, el "índice" de  la columna F es 6, pero los índices de los elementos de un `Array` son base 0 por lo que el índice para la columna F es 5.

Aparentemente lo anterior se debe a que las funciones de hoja de cálculo como `ROW()` y `COLUMN()` devuelven el número de renglón y columna respectivamente usando como base 1 pero en JavaScript los índices son base 0.

Comment: Mil gracias amigo, tiene toda la razón.... y gracias al foro por permitir mi pregunta.

Comment: @Marco Por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)